# how do I match & in and url exactly without messing xml entities using regex

Tags: html, regex

I just want to match & in the url but not the xml entities like &amp;&lt; etc.

```
<a href="/test/test2">Contact Us</a>
<a href="http://www.testassociation.com/test.html?ab=5&cd=5&ab=c" target="_blank">Customer Association</a>&amp;
```

http://www.testassociation.com/test.html?ab=5&cd=5&ab=c

I want to replace the `&` with `&amp;` but not disturb the other entities.

Sorry I am not getting idea how to do it.

I tried this:

```
(&)([a-z][^;]*)
```

Is there a better way.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Have you tried [using a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674) instead?

Comment: Your URL should be using `&amp;` anyway, otherwise some version of IE have a tendency to mess things up for you(try this as a URL part: `&section=doesnt_work` on IE7).

Comment: yeah thats is my requirment i want &amp; instead of &amp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to be completely accurate is like @vks says including all the list of entities.

You can find this list in the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

If you don't need to be so accurate, and having the longest entity &thetasym; with 8 characters you can use negative lookahead:

```
(?!&\w{1,8};)&
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mN8aM8/1)

Taking in mind that you will also miss everything with the form &dffa; even if it is not a valid entity

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!&amp|&lt)&
```

You can use something like this.You will have to list all &amp like words you want to miss.I have listed two.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tA9uG5/1

Edit

```
&(?=\w\w=)
```

use this if you dont want to list all.

Comment: That was just an example that &amp; &lt;...actually I need to ignore all xml entities not only these

Comment: You can add all you want to you want to miss by appending to that list.How else will regex know what it has to miss

Comment: you can add further by |&others like this.

Comment: but that is cumbersome...can't we compare all the entities in one shot

Comment: will & be always of form &ab= ?

Comment: try using this &(?=\w\w=)